# Sass/Scss - How to get partial variables as a list?

Tags: sass

I would like to loop over all the variables in a single partial, but I can't find away to automate this.

**The example:**

I have a partial named `_colors.scss`, it *only* contains colour variables.

```
$facebook: #305897;
$twitter: #31aae1;
$google: #da4936;
$pinterest: #c9151a;
```

These are already used across the site so I can't reformat them as a list.

I would like to do something like, foreach var in _colors return mixin.

But I can't find away to access them without calling each individually...

I am sure I am missing something obvious, and would appreciate someone pointing it out :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no shortcut for this.  You'll have to create a list out of them yourself.

```
$facebook: #305897;
$twitter: #31aae1;
$google: #da4936;
$pinterest: #c9151a;

$social: $facebook, $twitter, $google, $pinterest;
```